# Thread Pool Workers Overwhelmed With Runnables Crashing the JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, garbage-collection

**Brief**

I am running a multithreaded tcp server that uses a fixed thread pool with an unbounded Runnable queue. The clients dispatch the runnables to the pool.

In my stress test scenario, 600 clients attempt to login to the server and immediately broadcast messages to every other client *simultaneously* and *repeatedly to no end* and *without sleeping* (Right now the clients just discard the incoming messages). Using a quad-core with 1GB reserved for heap memory - and a parallel GC for both the young and old generations - the server crashes with a OOM exception after 20 minutes. Monitoring the garbage collector reveals that the tenured generation is slowly increasing, and a full GC only frees up a small fraction of memory. A snapshot of a full heap shows that the old generation is almost completely occupied by Runnables (and their outgoing references).

It seems the worker threads are not able to finish executing the Runnables faster than the clients are able to queue them for execution (For each incoming "event" to the server, the server will create 599 runnables as there are 600 - 1 clients - assuming they are all logged in at the time).

**Question**

Can someone please help me conceive a strategy on how to handle the overwhelmed thread pool workers?

**Also**

- If I bound the queue, what policy should I implement to handle rejected execution?
- If I increase the size of the heap, wouldn't that only prolong the OOM exception?
- A calculation can be made to measure the amount of work done in the aggregation of Runnables. Perhaps this measurement be used as a basis for a locking mechanism to coordinate clients' dispatching work?
- What reaction should the client experience when the server is overwhelmed with work?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use an unbounded queue. I cannot tell you what the bound should be; your load tests should give you an answer to that question. Anyhow, make the bound configurable: at least dynamycalliy configurable, better yet adaptable to some load measurement.
2. You did not tell us how the clients submit their requests, but if HTTP is involved, there already is a status code for the overloaded case: [503  Service Unavailable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.4).

Comment: thx edited my question to include tcp protocol. Do you have a suggestion on how to dynamically resize the capacity of the queue? Also, how should the client react during the unavailability of the server?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you limit the capacity of the queue and "push back" on the publisher to stop it publishing or drop the requests gracefully.  You can do the former b making the Queue block when its full.

You should be able to calculate your maximum throughput based on you network bandwidth and message size. If you are getting less than this, I would consider changing how your server distributes data.

Another approach is to make your message handling more efficient.  You could have each reading thread from each client write directly to the listening clients.  This avoids the need for an explicit queue (you might think of the buffers in the Socket as a queue of bytes) and limits the speed to whatever the server can handle.  It will also not use more memory under load (than it does when idle)

Using this approach you can achieve as high message rates as your network bandwidth can handle. (Even with a 10 Gig-E network) This moves the bottle neck elsewhere, meaning you still have a problem but your server shouldn't fail.

BTW: If you use direct ByteBuffers you can do this without creating garbage and with a minimum of heap. e.g. ~1 KB of heap per client.

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow throttle the incoming requests, and the mechanism for doing that should depend on the work you are trying to do. Anything else will simply result in an OOM under enough load, and thus open you up for DOS attacks (even unintentional ones).

Fundamentally, you have 4 choices:

1. Make clients wait until you are ready to accept their requests
2. Actively reject client requests until you are ready to accept new requests
3. Allow clients to timeout while trying to reach your server when it is not ready to receive requests
4. A blend of 2 or 3 of the above strategies.

The right strategy depends on how your real clients will react under the various circumstances – is it better for them to wait, possibly (effectively) indefinitely, or is it better that they know quickly that their work won't get done unless they try again later?

Whichever way you do it, you need to be able to count the number of tasks currently queued and either add a delay, block completely, or return an error condition based on the number of items in the queue.

A simple blocking strategy can be implemented by using a BlockingQueue implementation. However, this doesn't give particularly fine-grained control.

Or you can use a Semaphore to control permits to add tasks to the queue, which has the advantage of supplying a tryAcquire(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) method if you want to apply a mild throttling.

Whichever way, don't allow the threads that service the clients to grow without bounds, or else you'll simply end up with an OOM for a different reason!

Comment: I like the idea of using a semaphore. Do you think I can use it in conjunction with the workers' metric of throughput to specify when to wait based on the amount of work to be done in all runnables instead of just the size of how many runnables?

Comment: Yes, I guess you could calculate the average time it took a Task to be completed and create or destroy permits based on how that compared to your expected figure.

Comment: Incidentally, for your throughput test, you could simply cap the queue size at a couple of thousand and force the test harness threads to wait. You then tune the size of the worker thread pool until you see maximum number of tasks completed in an hour (or whatever period works). This means your worker threads are kept busy but your server never keels over with an OOM.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're doing load testing. I would determine what you consider to be "acceptable heavy load". What is the heaviest amount of traffic you can expect a single client to generate? Then double it. Or triple it. Or scale a manner similar to that. Use this threshold to throttle or deny clients that use this much bandwidth.

This has a number of perks. First, it gives you the kind of analysis you need to determine server load (users per server). Second it gives you a first line of defense against DDOS attacks.

Comment: Yes it is a load test. I am attempting to find out what an "acceptable heavy load" is based on its maximum throughput.

Comment: Personally, I feel that's putting the cart before the horse. I would calculate what the heavy load is based on the clients. How many messages per second can you expect your application to send?